# New module in admin always shows 404 page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

After updating [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788) for my Magento site (Magento CE version 1.9.2.1) and I added the module : https://bitbucket.org/magebit/whitelister/downloads. This module automatically sets white-list blocks.

ALC node in *config.xml*

```
<acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <magebit_whitelister translate="title" module="magebit_whitelister">
                        <title>Whitelister</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <magebit_horizonintegration translate="title">
                                <title>Magebit - Whitelister</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </magebit_horizonintegration>
                        </children>
                    </magebit_whitelister>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <magebit_whitelister>
                                        <title>Magebit - Whitelister</title>
                                    </magebit_whitelister>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

After installing this extention , flushing the cache , I try to logout and login into the admin, however, that always show a 404 page when reaching the second link in menu. Do you know how I can solve this error ?

Comment: Can you first check file permissions of newly added files in this modules?

Comment: I used Windows OS. I have just checked the permission of module, it is full control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Magento will don't understand our ACL menu if we don't declare the module and translate node. You need to add *translate="title"* and *module="magebit_whitelister"* in *config.xml*. The second ACL menu should be:

```
                       <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <magebit_whitelister translate="title" module="magebit_whitelister">
                                        <title>Magebit - Whitelister</title>
                                    </magebit_whitelister>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
```

Logout and login into Magento Admin again.

Comment: We also see here: https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/New-module-in-ADMIN-are-showing-A-404-page/m-p/21054#M1756